# Сетевая карта не выдаёт 1 гбит

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-server

Есть Windows server 2012. На нём стоит две гигабитные сетевые карты, которые работают в Тиминге. При загрузке по локальной сети, скорость не превышает 100 мбит/с., хотя с другого сервера, в той же сети, на тот же ресурс скорость выше. В настройках скорости и дуплекса нету пункта в 1000 мбит/c. С чем может быть связана данная проблема?

Comment: Драйвера на сетевые карты были скачены с официального сайта, конкретно по сборке оборудования, и сетевой карте.

Comment: Мегабит или мегабайт в секунду?

Comment: На коммутаторе агрегацию настроили?

Comment: С коммутатором всё впорядке, к нему подключены остальные сервера, которые работают нормально.

Comment: а коммутатор какую скорость показывает?

Comment: Не могу сказать, нет к нему доступа. Лишь знаю что настроен он правильно, и остальные сервера на нём работают хорошо.